# What is the best solution for multi lingual static Web site with GUI?

Tags: web, content-management-system

I'm looking for a Static Site Generator with GUI i.e. a static version of Wordpress.

After some searches on the Web, I found many solutions (Netlify CMS, Lektor, Grav and Publii).

1. Which is the best solution in order to obtain multilingual Web site via a plugin or without a lot of coding as with Jekyll or other solution?
2. In theory, all the previous solutions should support Gitlab or GitHub page. Which one is the best?
3. Which one do you suggest to use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

After several trials and testing, my final thoughts are the following:

1. [Grav](https://getgrav.org/) it is the ideal successor of Wordpress. It is faster and provides multilingual support and a lot of plugin. Unfortunately, the [plugin](https://github.com/BarryMode/grav-plugin-blackhole) that provides static Web site generation does not work
2. [Lektor](https://www.getlektor.com/) it is very simple to use. It provides multilingual support and static Web site generation. However, it is too spartan and in my opinion requires further improvement
3. [Publii](https://getpublii.com/) it is the most promising (app written in javascript-electron). It works entirely locally, easy to install, easy to use and provides static Web site generation with deploy to gitlab. It lacks of multilingual support (expected next year) and it has few themes.
4. [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) it works online directly on gitlab. It supports both hugo and gatsby framework and static Web site generation. I tried a [theme](https://github.com/matcornic/hugo-theme-learn) for the first that provide multilingual, but it is not very user friendly.
5. [Jekyll Now](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now) it is a faster way to use Jekyll as static Web site generation directly into gitlab. Unfortunately, it is not simple to use multilingual support and the "GUI" is not user friendly compared to the others.

In conclusion, my suggestion is to use Publii a new way to static Web site generation.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) for Static Site and integrating [Contentful API](https://www.contentful.com) to retrieve your content.

Contentful is a nice CMS service that supports localization.

Then you can easily deploy all to Netlify/Now.sh

Tutorial:
https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/gatsbyjs-and-contentful-in-five-minutes/